# Standard nginx.conf file is giving errors. Where to include server{} definition?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, nginx, ubuntu-12.04, uwsgi

I'm following [this deployment tutorial](http://www.slideshare.net/ssuser163469/deploying-flask-with-nginx-uwsgi) for running Flask with UWSGI and Nginx. At slide number 11 the contents of an nginx config file are given:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name myapp;

    root /var/www/myapp;
    try_files $uri @uwsgi;
    location @uwsgi {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/myapp.sock;
    }
}
```

and from the next slide (number 12) I understand that those contents should go into the file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/www`. So I did as I understood, but upon restarting nginx (`sudo service nginx restart`), I get an error saying `nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`.

The strange thing is that I never touched that nginx.conf file (I copied its contents [here on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/DUDZ5jBb)), bit it still causes an error.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong, and more importantly, how I can solve this? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
After the tips from @MohammadAbuShady , I fixed the space in the `@` and `uwsgi`, but I still get the same error. Running the suggested `sudo nginx -t` gives me the following information:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "uwsgi_param" in /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Does this give any new information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably the space between `@` and `uwsgi` , named locations should be written like this

```
location @uwsgi {
  #config
}
```

The error was reported inside `nginx.conf` because that is the config file that includes the other files inside `sites-enabled`, check line `72` in your pastebin

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

Also don't use `sudo service nginx restart` because by doing the shutdown is successful and the start up again fails, so you end up with a dead server, instead use `sudo service nginx reload` this way you wouldn't loose your uptime if your config is wrong.

To check where the config error is you can always run `sudo nginx -t` to test the config files.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I indeed made a mistake with the `@ uwsgi`. I fixed that but I still get the same error. I also ran your suggested `sudo nginx -t` and added the resulting error to my question. Does that give you any more information about what could be wrong?

Comment: it seems your nginx doesn't support the `uwsgi`, try running `sudo apt-get install nginx-full`, if i'm correct and recall correctly, it would say that it's going to uninstall another nginx and replace it by `nginx-full`, try that